# Get back to preious page after ios profile installed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, mobileprovision

I want whenever safari opens a profile and they profile is either installed or cancelled by the user after that the device get back to safari , safari redirect the user to the previous page .

This is exactly what i need :
i wanna have the code that detects a profile is installed and safari is now opened recently so i can then easily redirect my user to the page that  want (previous page).

Comment: Good to know what you want. Now tell us what you have done so far and where did you get stuck at. On So nobody writes code for you. We help you to understand what may not be working or how to do something specific but always starting from your code and not from scratch

Comment: i wanna have the code that detects a profile is installed and safari is now opened recently so i can then easily redirect my user to the page that  want (previous page).